# JavaScript to Find Index of Selected Dropdown Item, Pass to Hyperlink

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom, sharepoint-2010

I am having some trouble and after quite a bit of research have been unable to find a solution. I am working in SharePoint Designer 2010 and have an ASP.net dropdown populated by a list. I want to get the index value (e.g. 1) of the selected item from the dropdown list and pass it to the URL used to bring up the EditForm.aspx page. See below, and thank you for any help you can provide!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function redirect(url) {
        var ddl = document.getElementById(&apos;DropDownList1&apos;);
        alert(&quot;HI!&quot;);

        var index = ddl.selectedIndex;
        var value = ddl.options[index].value;

        location.href = url + value;
        return false;
    }
</script>

<asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="LinkButton1"
                href="https://chartiscorp.sp.ex3.secureserver.net/Lists/System_Information/EditForm.aspx?id="
                onclientclick="javascript:redirect(this.href)">Edit System Info</asp:LinkButton>

<asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="DropDownList1" DataValueField="Title"
                  DataTextField="Title" DataSourceID="spdatasource1" />
```

Comment: Please add the code for `DropDownList1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the rendered ID:

```
var ddl = document.getElementById('<%=DropDownList1.ClientID%>');
```

and the [`OnClientClick` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-AT/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.onclientclick.aspx) of the `LinkButton`:

```
<asp:LinkButton onclientclick="...">
```

To get the index just use

```
var index = ddl.selectedIndex;
```

or if you want to get the value use

```
var value = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
```

I would suggest doing the redirect in a function, not the HTML attribute. Bringing all together:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function redirect(url) {
        var ddl = document.getElementById('<%=DropDownList1.ClientID%>'),
            index = ddl.selectedIndex,
            value = ddl.options[index].value;

        location.href = url + value;
        return false;
    }
</script>
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="LinkButton1"
                href="../Lists/System_Information/EditForm.aspx?id="
                onclientclick="redirect(this.href)">LinkText</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="DropDownList1" DataValueField="Title"
                  DataTextField="Title" DataSourceID="spdatasource1" />
```

[This jsfiddle shows a demo of the rendered output.](http://jsfiddle.net/yu3Z9/)

Comment: I don't think my JavaScript function is getting called for some reason. I added 'code'alert(url + value);'code' and nothing came up

Comment: You'll have to use the `OnClientClick` event. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so  much for the help with the code. I moved the script so that it is right under 

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">

It seems this was the right move but now I am getting an error saying that "Code blocks are not allowed in this file"?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2007/04/26/code-blocks-are-not-allowed-in-this-file-using-server-side-code-with-sharepoint.aspx

Comment: Is there a particular area the javascript should be placed in?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Sharepoint, didn't even know the scripts problem, just found the post after searching. From a general HTML, CSS, JavaScript perspective, You should load JavaScript as late as possible to increase performance on client side. The script in your case I would add right before `</body>`.

Comment: I am sure it is a small difference at this point. I appreciate the help.

Comment: I have done a little more research and find that the javascript error is occurring at 

var index = ddl.selectedIndex

Any thoughts?

Comment: It's not giving me an actual output of what the error is, but if I put 

alert("HI!");

after that, it doesn't pop-up. Anywhere before that and it does.

Comment: You did ignore the first line of my answer. If you look at the resulting HTML code in your browser, you'll see that the ID of the `DropDownList` is not `DropDownList1`. Additionally you should not need to escape the quotation marks.

Comment: When I try to use 

<%=DropDownList1%>

I get an error: A name was started with an invalid character. var ddl = document.getElementById('') but I don't get the error without the notation. I see what you're saying though.